# Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to expected argument type '[Any]!'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to generate a list to populate a `DownPicker`

```
var personDownPicker: DownPicker!
@IBOutlet weak var servicioTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let data = NSMutableArray()
        data.add("1")
        data.add("2")
        data.add("3")

        self.personDownPicker = DownPicker(textField: self.servicioTextField, withData: data)

        }
```

But, I get this error each time that I need assign the variable `data`

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSMutableArray' to expected argument
>   type '[Any]!'

How I can assign this lit to my DownPicker?

Comment: Why are you using `NSMutableArray` in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to be using `NSMutableArray` here. Just use native Swift data types:

```
let data = ["1", "2", "3"]
self.personDownPicker = DownPicker(textField: self.servicioTextField,
                                    withData: data as NSMutableArray)
```